# JavaScript code does not want to run at all

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making my quiz,if he answers correctly to move it to the next question,if it does not answer correctly then drop the warning!
but I got a little stuck
I can't find out what I'm wrong about!
I'm certainly wrong about for loop but I don't know which part!

```
var questions = [{
    question: "Best internet service provider is\n(a) Carrier\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) VIP/Telecom",
    answer: "a"
  },
  {
    questions: "Bad internet service provider is \n(a) VIP/Telecom\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) Carrier",
    answer: "b"
  },

]

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
{
    var starter = window.question(questions[i].question);
  if(starter == questions[i].answer)
  {
    alert("LIKE");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("WRONG!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `window.question` defined? It doesn't exist in the snippet you provided so it's going to throw an error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't provide enough information about the question. However, I am assuming that you want to prompt the user to answer your questions and if they get it right you will display "LIKE" otherwise "WRONG", something like the picture below.

[image]

Based on this assumption here is a working solution:

```js
var questions = [{
    question: "Best internet service provider is\n(a) Carrier\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) VIP/Telecom",
    answer: "a"
  },
  {
    questions: "Bad internet service provider is \n(a) VIP/Telecom\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) Carrier",
    answer: "b"
  },

]

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var starter = prompt(questions[i].question);
  if (starter == questions[i].answer) {
    alert("LIKE");
  } else {
    alert("WRONG!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using `window.question`? Simply use your questions var:

```js
var questions = [{
    question: "Best internet service provider is\n(a) Carrier\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) VIP/Telecom",
    answer: "a"
  },
  {
    questions: "Bad internet service provider is \n(a) VIP/Telecom\n\(b) AT&T\n(c) Carrier",
    answer: "b"
  },

]

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
{
    var starter = questions[i].question;
  if(starter == questions[i].answer)
  {
    alert("LIKE");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("WRONG!");
  }
}
```

Comment: `starter !== answer`

Comment: Nowhere do I see my question or the answers offered!
Može se vidjeti samo Pogrešna uzbuna

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question because you don't describe the problem very well. Given the information you provided I am assuming you are building an html form and using javascript to change the question and answer options on the markup if the user answers correctly. The code you posted will never work because

```
// this is the question
// NOTE: the variable name should really be "question" or "currentQuestion", not "starter"
 var starter = window.question(questions[i].question); // not sure why "window"

// this is the answer
questions[i].answer

// so 
starter !== questions[i].answer will always be true
```

What you need is compare the user input (I imagine a checkbox for each option) with the value of the answer, so each checkbox needs to have its `value` property set to a different letter, which then you compare with the correct answer.

So you would need something like this (this was done in 15m just to give you an idea. The design is not the best--I suggest you improve on it).

```js
var questions = [
        {
          question: 'Best internet service provider is:',
          options: [
            {
              provider: 'Carrier',
              value: 'a'
            },
            {
              provider: 'AT&T',
              value: 'b'
            },
            {
              provider: 'VIP/Telecom',
              value: 'c'
            }
          ],
          answer: 'a'
        },
        {
          question: 'Worst internet service provider is:',
          options: [
            {
              provider: 'VIP/Telecom',
              value: 'a'
            },
            {
              provider: 'AT&T',
              value: 'b'
            },
            {
              provider: 'Carrier',
              value: 'c'
            }
          ],
          answer: 'b'
        }
      ];
      var counter = 0;
      var questionSet = questions[counter];
      var title = document.getElementById('title');
      var form = document.getElementById('form');

      const createTemplate = () => {
        title.innerText = questionSet['question'];
        form.innerHTML = getCheckboxes();

        for (let i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
          let checkbox = form.elements[i];

          checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
            if (e.target.value === questionSet['answer']) {
              counter++;
              alert('You got it!');

              if (counter < questions.length) {
                questionSet = questions[counter];
                createTemplate();
              }
            } else {
             alert('Try again');
            }

          });
        }
      };

      function getCheckboxes() {
        let html = '';

        questionSet['options'].forEach(item => {
          html += `
            <div>
              <label>${item['value']}. ${item['provider']}<label>
              <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value=${item['value']}>
            <\div>
            `;
        });

        return html;
      }

      createTemplate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    <form action="" id="form"></form>
  </body>
</html>
```